# DockerHub API Authentication using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerpy, docker-api

I'm working on a project with Python(3.6) in which I need to implement Docker Hub API to create a repository on user's docker hub account and push his docker image.

Real Scenario: User will provide his source code along with Dockerfile, his username and apikey of docker cloud, then I have to create a repository on his account and build a Docker image of his source code and push to his docker hub account.

Here's what I have tried:

```
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)
    temp_dir_path = os.path.join(tempdir)
    archive_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'archives/', deployment.sourceFile.name)
    print(archive_path)
    # Extract uploaded archive inside temporary dir
    patoolib.extract_archive(archive_path, outdir=temp_dir_path)
    # Try to retrieve path of dockerfile directory
    docker_glob = os.path.join(temp_dir_path, "*", "Dockerfile")
    print(docker_glob)
    docker_file = glob.glob(docker_glob)[0]
    docker_folder = os.path.dirname(docker_file)
    print(docker_folder)
    docker_client = docker.from_env()
    print("Start Building your docker image...")
    docker_client.login(username='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD')
    docker_client.images.build(path=docker_folder, gzip=False, tag=deployment.deploymentName)
    image = docker_client.images.get(deployment.deploymentName)
    shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
    img_id = image.short_id
    print(img_id)
```

As you can see currently I'm pushing the image to my own default/repo but I want to create a repo on user's account and then push the image to his own account. AND also, can I use `apikey` instead of `password` in `login()` method?

How can I achieve this thing?

Help me, please!

Thank You,
Abdul

Comment: Not clear what docker library you're using

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, I'm using Python SDK of Docker as https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Have you tried using the push function? It doesn't say anything about api keys https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.push

Comment: it also has a parameter `auth_config` dict which should include `username` and `password`.

Comment: Yes, that's what it says. Are you getting any errors, or do you just prefer using an API key? (which only exists for Docker Cloud, I believe, not part of the Docker API)

Comment: Actually, the end user will need to pass his credentials, so, as you know the user will always prefer API_KEY instead of the password and even it's a correct way to authenticate third party users.

Comment: An API KEY is hard to remember and can be just as insecure as a password, so "always" is a little presumptuous

Comment: I was talking from the security perspective.